# Adding base layer for WMS layers from WMSCapabilitiesStore

Tags: geoext

I'm using the following code to get my WMS layers through GeoExt's WMSCapabilities store and display them in a grid for the users to select and add them to the map panel. but i need to add also a base layer but i couldn't succeed.

```
 Ext.onReady(function() {
        app = new Ext.Viewport({
            layout: "border",
            items: items
        });
    });
    var map = new OpenLayers.Map(null, {
          projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:3857"),
          allOverlays: true,
          maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(-20037508.34, -20037508.34,
                                 20037508.34, 20037508.34),
          units: 'm',
          numZoomLevels: 10
      });
    items.push({
        xtype: "gx_mappanel",
        ref: "mapPanel",
        region: "center",
        map: map
    });
    controls.push(
        new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation(),
        new OpenLayers.Control.Attribution(),
        new OpenLayers.Control.PanPanel(),
        new OpenLayers.Control.ZoomPanel()
    );
    items.push({
        xtype: "grid",
        ref: "capsGrid", // makes the grid available as app.capsGrid
        title: "Request/Status Map Layers",
        region: "north",
        height: 150,
        viewConfig: {forceFit: true},
        store: new GeoExt.data.WMSCapabilitiesStore({
            url: "data/getcap_1.3.0.xml",
            autoLoad: true
        }),
        columns: [
            {header: "Name", dataIndex: "name", sortable: true},
            {header: "Title", dataIndex: "title", sortable: true},
            {header: "Abstract", dataIndex: "abstract"}
        ],
        bbar: [{
            text: "Add to Map",
            handler: function() {
                app.capsGrid.getSelectionModel().each(function(record) {
                    var clone = record.clone();
                    bbox = clone.get("llbbox");
                    clone.getLayer().mergeNewParams({
                        format: "image/png",
                        transparent: true
                    });
                    var osmLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM();
                    //app.mapPanel.layers.add(osmLayer);
                    app.mapPanel.layers.add(clone);
                    app.mapPanel.map.zoomToExtent(
                        OpenLayers.Bounds.fromArray(clone.get("llbbox")).transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:3857"))
                    );
                });
            }
        }]
    });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to request your layer in the correct srs and transform the bbox you grabbed from the clone variable

Comment: Thank you, but that is what i have already did.

Comment: Can you explain what exactly does not work?

Comment: The problem was adding base layer such as OpenStreetMap, because the base layer is not part of the WMS layers loaded in a grid panel from WMSCapabilitiesStore. fortunately i managed to make it work by creating OSM layer (osmLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM();  map.addlayer(osmLayer); this way the baselayer is always loaded when the page is loaded and we can add other WMS layers on top of it by selecting from the list of layers on the grid.

Comment: So this means your problem is solved? Or did you want to add the osm-layer dynamically?

Comment: It is already solved just manually, but is their a way to add it dynamically.

Comment: Yes, for example with a second button-object in the bbar-array where you just use your two lines of code to add the osm-layer as handler function.But to have a default baselayer is probably also nice, isn't it?

Comment: Thank you, well said the default is good, but your option also helps to add additional base map. that means the bbar accepts an array of buttons, right?

Comment: Yes, just copy the object to something like  bbar=[ { ... },{ ...}];

Comment: The OSM base map opens with full extent but i want to center it to a default location like map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(long, lat).transform(wgs84, google)). wgs84 and google are variables referring the projection objects. but still not working. what went wrong? any idea?